# how to have conditional Help text for a listbox field

Tags: ajax, theming, javascript

Remember the create password page of Drupal! While you are entering characters it tells you how strong your password is!

Now I want to have something like this in a list box but a bit different. I want to show an image and a text depend on the item which is selected in the list box! How can I do it? My first try was adding some code in help text of the field, but it doesn't work. What are your suggestions?

I can not use conditional field because I must add 60 conditions and it is illogical. Ao I need a programmatic way. The java script code and how to I make it dependent to two list boxes?
I add a markup field to my content type but I don't know who to find which item is selected in the list box with ajax ind how to show an item depend on it.

Answer (score 4):

You don't have to code for this. You can use [Conditional Fields](https://www.drupal.org/project/conditional_fields) to achieve it.

You can then use "Manage Dependencies" section (alongside manage display) to set the dependencies:

[image]

Then you can see the different fields being enabled or disabled depending on the entered input:

List option "**No**" Result:

[image]

List option "**Yes**" Result:

[image]

Comment: I know about field conditional. but what I need to show is not a field! I want to show an some description and image as the result of choosing an item in a list box!

Comment: Just thoughts, you can use a non-editable text field with pre-filled text for description: http://stackoverflow.com/a/5418607/260665 in conjunction with Conditional fields. There should be something for image in the same way, otherwise, you can hook the view and modify it for image alone.

Comment: in this way I should add 59 fields because I have 59 different images and text to show depend on the item which is selected from the listbox! in addition, it is a illogical way I ask for a programmatic approach.